# Plot data frame fast and with correct date format

Tags: python, pandas, date, matplotlib

I have the data as in the screenshot, it is in a dataframe format, I would like to plot the dataframe fast and with correct date format.

The code as follow is much fast than using e.g `plt.plot(df["Date"], df["D30"])`

```
df.plot(marker='.', linestyle='none')
```

So that I would like to keep using the dataframe.plot() functionality directly because it is much faster than plot each column against the "Date" column separately. However, as shown in the graph, the date is not correct. My actually starting Date is 2006-01-10, but in the figure, it is shown from 70-01 (1970-01-01).

For me, the official documentation of matplotlib DateFormatter is quite confusing and not so helpful. I tried to google a easy and clear solution, but most answers are related to `plt.plot(x, y)` where `x` is `Date` and `y` is the actual value. After that it is easy to adjust the format of the "Date" in the figure. But it will make my plot super slow since I am plotting 11 columns in total.

Any idea how I can plot data frame fast and with correct date format

```
import os
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
date_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%y%m')

df_file = r"C:\Codes\df_file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path_file)
print(len(df), df.info(), df["Date"][0], type(df["Date"][0]))
df.head(2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12.0, 8.0))
df.plot(marker='.', linestyle='none')
plt.title("data_frame_show date", fontsize=16)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dtFmt)
plt.legend(loc=(1.04, 0))
plt.show()
```

[image]

partial input:

```
Date,D10,D30,D60,D91,D122,D152,D182,D273,D365,D547,D730
2006-01-10,,0.1373444,0.1544265,0.1541397,0.1429375,0.1421464,0.1426055,0.1460771,0.1486266,0.1551848,0.1593932
2006-01-11,,0.135426,0.1411246,0.141093,0.1384091,0.1383636,0.1395791,0.1438944,0.1469191,0.1553112,0.1598582
2006-01-12,,0.1311339,0.1292621,0.1304292,0.1363482,0.1362213,0.1367843,0.1404174,0.1439877,0.152306,0.1568677
2006-01-13,,0.1594458,0.1355387,0.1367246,0.1434708,0.143745,0.1441349,0.1453056,0.1481918,0.157193,0.1607564
2006-01-16,,0.1374846,0.1182223,0.1272385,0.1415359,0.1418881,0.1430098,0.1468544,0.1496407,0.1547714,0.158936
2006-01-17,,0.1453834,0.1418838,0.143198,0.1437924,0.143473,0.1440987,0.1473208,0.1501543,0.1590842,0.1629096
2006-01-18,,0.1385479,0.141472,0.1481763,0.1515037,0.1511353,0.1511544,0.1535245,0.1554254,0.1626349,0.1663554
2006-01-19,,0.1639788,0.1462084,0.1483903,0.1486906,0.1483109,0.1492335,0.1539002,0.1563708,0.1611751,0.1644693
2006-01-20,,0.189771,0.178394,0.1638331,0.1565402,0.1559029,0.1553547,0.1526479,0.1516396,0.1614136,0.1646431
2006-01-23,,0.1420271,0.1570005,0.1614942,0.1607205,0.1605297,0.1630065,0.1653838,0.1642349,0.166809,0.1701779
2006-01-24,,0.1814291,0.1633585,0.1563364,0.1548823,0.15382,0.1545099,0.1590869,0.1609158,0.1653819,0.1681759
2006-01-25,,0.1272998,0.1445222,0.1487031,0.1522032,0.152714,0.1524364,0.1532192,0.1550062,0.1635665,0.1658293
2006-01-26,,0.1392162,0.1413034,0.1443807,0.1476261,0.1482458,0.1473548,0.1471019,0.1493254,0.1578586,0.160699
2006-01-27,,0.1360269,0.1374056,0.1387952,0.1426731,0.1441445,0.144917,0.1462428,0.1478979,0.1519537,0.1550311
2006-01-30,,0.1439245,0.1430108,0.1434628,0.1448731,0.1450397,0.1454756,0.1467621,0.1487521,0.1538424,0.1561802
2006-01-31,,0.1483135,0.1468713,0.1473837,0.1519043,0.1519379,0.1502139,0.1504632,0.1529254,0.1571567,0.1589795
2006-02-01,,0.1464208,0.1447363,0.1443483,0.1459808,0.1477726,0.1505124,0.1520256,0.1535773,0.1589145,0.1607383
2006-02-02,,0.1484249,0.1414394,0.1412338,0.1497531,0.1500731,0.1475751,0.147502,0.1512457,0.1571017,0.1606797
2006-02-03,,0.1496503,0.1485318,0.1502473,0.1565336,0.156727,0.1556335,0.1560396,0.1579241,0.1619183,0.1634751
2006-02-06,,0.149966,0.1457216,0.1475524,0.1539103,0.1546401,0.154973,0.1553681,0.1570598,0.161173,0.1630743
2006-02-08,,0.1463649,0.1436135,0.1454147,0.1498372,0.1507231,0.1520234,0.1538407,0.1563603,0.1617697,0.1639547
2006-02-09,,0.1401312,0.1432856,0.1437166,0.1443243,0.1463163,0.148681,0.1496198,0.1516376,0.1584639,0.1615756
2006-02-10,,0.1339916,0.1405194,0.1432779,0.1464605,0.1470921,0.1484831,0.1514307,0.1550715,0.1599564,0.1623171
2006-02-13,,0.1470304,0.1423007,0.1446087,0.1470668,0.1485171,0.1503383,0.1508497,0.1532987,0.1591155,0.1615874
2006-02-14,,0.1454322,0.1449017,0.1455735,0.1462286,0.1478059,0.1501469,0.1522522,0.1541999,0.157668,0.1601427
2006-02-15,,0.1429312,0.1455881,0.1464055,0.1471812,0.1489883,0.1514654,0.153837,0.1559375,0.16082,0.1631557
2006-02-16,,0.134637,0.1373471,0.140634,0.1432172,0.145788,0.14875,0.1507805,0.15325,0.1581015,0.1613797
2006-02-20,,0.1303785,0.1334454,0.139216,0.1423217,0.1454704,0.1477552,0.1487534,0.1509405,0.1554398,0.1588761
2006-02-21,,0.1359587,0.1370814,0.1416117,0.1418016,0.1441761,0.1468109,0.1476679,0.1496546,0.1561362,0.1607204
2006-02-22,,0.1302253,0.1337104,0.1415016,0.141451,0.1438881,0.1467031,0.1502449,0.1514018,0.1531452,0.1582335
2006-02-23,,0.1282022,0.1333902,0.1342376,0.1385976,0.1453201,0.1481733,0.1490296,0.1512885,0.1554035,0.1593463
2006-02-24,,0.1269229,0.1304391,0.1348061,0.1378378,0.1419301,0.1442134,0.1472283,0.1507224,0.1555662,0.1595938
2006-02-27,,0.1254707,0.128201,0.1334554,0.1374389,0.1427246,0.1446071,0.1465459,0.1496113,0.1541296,0.1578174
2006-02-28,,0.1346332,0.1361773,0.139586,0.1421924,0.1468084,0.1489651,0.1505661,0.1541479,0.1606205,0.1675438
2006-03-01,,0.1301198,0.1318495,0.1343342,0.1376886,0.1434328,0.1459977,0.1490832,0.1525961,0.1557153,0.1593923
2006-03-02,,0.1304425,0.1347556,0.1398592,0.1420431,0.1457691,0.1479747,0.1510143,0.1544964,0.1589201,0.1616325
2006-03-03,,0.1311674,0.1339681,0.138887,0.1418598,0.1451706,0.1472144,0.1495689,0.1536886,0.1599843,0.162247
2006-03-06,,0.1308081,0.1367775,0.1412145,0.1436582,0.1480171,0.1495588,0.1511633,0.1545973,0.1588486,0.1616268
2006-03-07,,0.1344355,0.1387528,0.143365,0.1459607,0.1482421,0.1491656,0.1512236,0.1550063,0.1593201,0.1615385
```

Comment: Check the type of Date column (`df.info()`). If the format is object and NOT datetime, this type of problem occurs. You will need to convert `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: @Redox, I already tried like this, it does not work. `df` comes from reading a csv file. and the "Date" column is str. With your proposed adjustment, this "Date" column will appear in the y part and the x part still starts with 70-01.

Comment: @Redox, I have edited the post, also have provided partial input. The actual number of row is 4250

Comment: What if you set the date as the index after having transform the date to datetime?
df = df.assign(Date= lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")).set_index("Date")

Comment: @XYZ moreover, I like to use plotly as pandas backend `pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"` to explore time series in a more convenient and interactive way.

Answer (score 1):

When plotting time series, pandas takes the index for the x-axis when calling the plot function.

I would suggest to:

```py
df = df.assign(
    Date=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x["Date"], format="%Y-%m%d")
).set_index("Date")
```